# Is it possible to set edit_handlers in wagtail dynamically?

Tags: django, wagtail

In Wagtail (2.1), I'd like to show `edit_handlers` based on the `instance` of a Page object.
Digging in Wagtail, I see that `edit_handlers` is a classbased function, hence no request or instance object is available.

Is this even possible?

As far as I know, I can only achieve this by overriding the function based view `edit` (`https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py#L311`) copying the whole function, and changing the edit_handler assignment here (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py#L329) based on `latest_revision`.

Then I'd have to create a new `urls.py` that picks up on this overridden `edit` view for that specific Page type.

*update with example*

As an example, I'd like to be able to edit the Tags of a Storypage in case the loggedin username equals 'tagman'. If not, then I should not be able to edit the tags.

By default the content_panels, promote_panels & setting_panels are used.
However, based on request.user, I want to show the promote_panels_alternative (which include the tags).

```
class StoryPage(Page):
    tags = ParentalManyToManyField('tags.Tag', blank=True, related_name='tags')

    edit_handler = CustomEditHandler

    promote_panels_alternative = Page.promote_panels + [FieldPanel('tags', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple), ]


class CustomEditHandler(TabbedInterface): ?
```

In thise CustomEditHandler class (which I'm not sure what to subclass from), I'd overwrite a method (not sure which one), that by default creates the tabs a la `https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py#L785` and then based on `instance` or `request` I can build up the `TabbedInterface` using `StoryPage.promote_panels_alternative` instead of `StoryPage.promote_panels`.

Answer (score -1):

No need to override the `edit` view. The page instance is available as `self.instance`. And since Wagtail 2.1 the request is available as `self.request`.

Comment: There is no self, just cls ?

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion, you were talking about customizing `Page.get_edit_handler` while I was talking about customizing the `EditHandler`s themselves.

You cannot customize `Page.get_edit_handler` per `Page` instance for now, but you can customize the behaviour of `EditHandler`s. The whole `EditHandler` tree is rebuilt when binding the instance to the `Page`. You can customize for example `ObjectList` to hide a `FieldPanel` by redefining `on_instance_bound`, use `super` to build the children of that `ObjectList`, then iterate again over `self.children` to remove some of them.